# CSS3 (like -webkit-animation-*) is working fine in IE, but not in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, animation, webkit

CSS3 (like `-webkit-animation-*`) is working fine in IE, but not in Chrome.

How is it possible? Are there any network level security implementations stopping the animation to render?

This is happening in Prod, not in Local.

Comment: Please provide a working sample of CSS3 which is affected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any security issue in chrome to stop animations. Actually, IE ignores all instructions starting with -webkit-*, but evaluates (until version 9 if i don't go wrong) rules starting with -ms-*. Newer versions do not need any prefix. Chrome, generally doesn't also need the -webkit-* prefix, it is generally needed by Safari.

Try to check your code for other errors, and try to provide some code, in order to better understand what is not actually really working there.